# Replacing background graphics of a PowerPoint theme

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, graphics, microsoft-office-2010

I'm using this theme ([this is my .pptx file](http://www.mediafire.com/?25ptrthd1nibrga)).

[image: Theme screenshot]

When I check the "Hide Background Graphics" checkbox, the butterflies' graphics disappear.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to replace such `buttefly graphic` by my own designed one, how can I do that?

Comment: Need your link about the theme and the powerpoint file you are working on.

Answer (score 99):

I had the same issue. To edit the background:

1. Click on **View -> Slide Master**
2. Click on **View -> Slide Master** *again*.

All the background images will become editable and copy-pasteable.

Definitely not intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

In this case go to your Background Style and click on format background where there is a option picture/texture fill. Click on it and you can find the insert picture option. I think you can upload your desired background picture from here.

Comment: I can do it.
We can use **Slide Master** (view -> Slide Master) to change graphics or copy graphics.
If you want to copy more than 1 icon, you can keep Shift key and select objects. 
After please Ctrl-C.

Thought more theme, using Slide Master and press Ctr-V to paste objects.
 ^^! Very easy!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally done by editing the slide master for the theme. When you do this, however, the effects are permanent, so your future presentations with this theme will have the new background images. Sounds like that's what you are looking for.

Check Powerpoint help and search for "slide master". It should give you enough to do what you're looking for.